# Android asset file not showing up. Getting File not found error

Tags: android

I have included some html files in my assets folder but when I try to show them in a webview I am getting a file not found error. I cant see the file in my //data/data/files folder in fileexplorer as well. Not sure what is the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Show some code about how you try to put it into your webview. Assets are i think always loaded at runtime (eg. no R.assets.)

Answer (score 0):

I don' t know what you' ve tried so far, but this is one proper way to get files from assets folder at runtime:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("YourHTML.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

I show a help file that is driven off of a static html file I put in my asset folder.  This is my code:

```
BufferedReader in = null; 
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

String assetFile = "help.html";

try { 

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open( assetFile ),"utf-8")); 
    String line; 

    /* line by line read in the file */
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) buffer.append(line); 

} catch (IOException e) { 
} finally { 
    try { in.close(); } catch (Exception e) {} 
} 

WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.help_view);
wv.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, buffer.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```